# images in slider are displayed smaller than actual image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am trying to display a single image on its own and multiple images in a slider. Only issue is I can't get images in a slider to match the same height as a single image, it is displaying the images a lot smaller. How can I get the size of the images to match? Even if I get the image the same height and width, the images are displayed smaller in the slider.

Here is an app showing the images: [HERE](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text9.php)

(ignore the notice error)

Code displaying images and slider:

```
<?php 
    //start:procedure image
    if(count($arrImageFile[$key]) == 1){
        foreach ($arrImageFile[$key] as $i) {
?>
<p><img alt="<?php echo $i; ?>" height="200" width="200" src="<?php echo 'ImageFiles/'.$i; ?>"></p>
<?php 
        } 
    } else if(count($arrImageFile[$key]) > 1){
?>

<style>
    #galleriaimage_<?php echo $key; ?>{ width: 200px; height: 250px; background: #000 }
</style>
<div id="galleriaimage_<?php echo $key; ?>">
<?php foreach ($arrImageFile[$key] as $i) { ?>
    <img alt="<?php echo $i; ?>" height="250" width="200" src="<?php echo 'ImageFiles/'.$i; ?>">
<?php } ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Galleria.loadTheme('jquery/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
    Galleria.run('#galleriaimage_<?php echo $key; ?>');
</script>

<?php
    }
```

Comment: I think, JQ overwrites images heights, so you should look into JQ functions

Comment: Galleria is designed to perform this behaviour, it automatically resizes it's "thumbnails" to fit, you'd be better off choosing a carousel library that does what you want -- rather than hack this one (considering there are no options to control thumbnail sizing in the documentation).

Comment: @pebbl I am talking about the main image, not the small thumbnail images, all I want is the main image to be 250px for height and 200px in width in the galleria slider

Comment: @user2056342 but the large "images" in the main slider (not the thumbnail slider) aren't images, they are converted to iframes by jplayer (by the looks of things).

Comment: @pebbl Oh my god I was suppose to create a seperate demo on another issue but I accidentally overwritten it over this one. I got the demo back up showing the images

Comment: Ah things make a bit more sense now, unfortunately my advice is still the same. Gallaria seems designed to always scale the images to fit it's "stage" dimensions. So the only way you can control what size they appear at is to change the dimensions of the stage (as you are already doing with your css on `#galleriaimage_7` or by using Pavel's answer) but you have to take into account Gallaria's internal padding, thumbnail carousel and other GUI metrics if you want to get exact image dimensions. Trial and error with a few different dimensions should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the **`imageCrop`** parameter.

http://galleria.io/docs/options/imageCrop/

> type: Boolean or String default: false

Defines how the main image will be cropped inside it’s container.

> **true**: all images are scaled to fill the stage, centered and cropped.
>   **false**: scales down so the entire image fits.
>   **‘height’**: scales the image to fill the height of the stage.
>   **‘width’**: will scale the image to fill the width of the stage.
>   **‘landscape’** will fill up images that has landscape proportions, but scale portrait images to fit inside the container.
>   **‘portrait’** is like ‘landscape’ but the other way around.

You may even have success combining the parameters:

```
Galleria.run('#galleria', {
    height: 250,
    imageCrop: 'height'
});
```

Or setting the height/width via CSS, and using imageCrop alone.

Answer (score 0):

[there are options for your gallery](http://galleria.io/docs/options)

```
Galleria.run('#galleria', {
    height: 400
});
```

you can use a variable to define height for example.

Answer (score 0):

The terminology is a little confusing but my understanding is that your original images are 1024x768 but Galleria scales the featured image to fit the stage and the question is how to increase the featured image size.

In your example the stage is set to be 200x200 by this style `#galleriaimage_7{ width: 200px; height: 200px; background: #000; }`.

In the console I changed those style dimensions to `width: 1024px; height: 768px;` and refreshed Galleria by running `Galleria.run('#galleriaimage_7');` and the script parses the style to set the stage size.  There is still extra padding in the black background so you would either need to make the stage even larger or edit the styles to remove padding.

[image]